# retrieve elements with the same foreign key value django python

Tags: python, mysql, django, view, request

please, how can i get all elemnts with the same foreingnkey on my web page; i use mysql database to store all data; then i send queries to get all data from mysql database to my page html, i try to make a filter in but it didn't work.
models.py:
class tsf(models.Model):

```
 perimetre = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
    production_tsf = models.ForeignKey(production, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    tsf_periode_1 = models.ForeignKey(periode_1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    tsf_periode_2 = models.ForeignKey(periode_2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    tsf_periode_3 = models.ForeignKey(periode_3, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    tsf_periode_4 = models.ForeignKey(periode_4, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.perimetre) if self.perimetre else ''
```

views.py:

```
def tsf_projet(request, id_production):
    new_tsf = forms.tsf_form()
    diction={'tsf_configuration':new_tsf, 'title':"configuration de la TSF" }

    if request.method== 'POST':
        new_tsf = forms.tsf_form(request.POST)
        if new_tsf.is_valid():
            new_tsf.save(commit=True)

            perimetre = new_tsf.cleaned_data['perimetre']
            tsf_periode_1 = new_tsf.cleaned_data['tsf_periode_1']
            tsf_periode_2 = new_tsf.cleaned_data['tsf_periode_2']
            tsf_periode_3 = new_tsf.cleaned_data['tsf_periode_3']
            tsf_periode_4 = new_tsf.cleaned_data['tsf_periode_4']

            diction.update({'perimetre':perimetre})
            diction.update({'tsf_periode_1':tsf_periode_1})
            diction.update({'tsf_periode_2':tsf_periode_2})
            diction.update({'tsf_periode_3':tsf_periode_3})
            diction.update({'tsf_periode_4':tsf_periode_4})
            #return production_liste(request)
    prod = production.objects.filter()
    tsf_new=tsf.objects.filter()
    diction={'tsf_affichage':tsf_new, 'tsf_configuration':new_tsf, 'title':"configuration de la TSF", 'affichage_nom':prod}

    return render(request, 'simulation/tsf_projet.html', context=diction)
```

html doc:

```
{% for ts in tsf_affichage  %}
{% for af in affichage_nom %}
  {% if af.id == ts.production_tsf_id %} <!--comment je fais le filtre ?-->
<tr>
  <td> {{ts.production_tsf.nom}}  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td> {{ts.perimetre}}  </td>
  <td></td>

  <td> {{ts.tsf_periode_1.taxe}} </td>
  <td></td>
  <td> {{ts.tsf_periode_2.taxe}} </td>
  <td></td>
  <td> {{ts.tsf_periode_3.taxe}} </td>
  <td></td>
  <td> {{ts.tsf_periode_4.taxe}} </td>
  <td></td>
  <td> {{ts.production_tsf.calcule_production}} </td>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the similar situation and searching for its solution. I had the following models

```
class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)                   
    groups = models.IntegerField()
 
class GroupPin(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

I wanted to access all group pins for a session. I did the following:
I passed a session object in the template and used following code to access all associated grouppin objects.

```
{% for g_pin in session.grouppin_set.all%}
  {{g_pin.pin}}
{% endfor %}
```

> So the '_set.all' will do the required work.

Assuming you want to get all `tsf` objects having a particular foreign key (production object with id_production id), you can simply pass the production object in the template by replacing `prod = production.objects.filter()` line with the following line.

```
prod = production.objects.get(id=production_id) # you need to update this code for the case when the object does not exists.
```

Next, pass this object to your template.

```
diction={ 'tsf_configuration':new_tsf, 'title':"configuration de la TSF", 'production':prod}
```

Finally, you just need to update your template as following

```
{% for ts in production.tsf_set.all %}
  <tr>
   <td> {{ts.production_tsf.nom}}  </td>
   <td></td>
   <td> {{ts.perimetre}}  </td>
   <td></td>

   <td> {{ts.tsf_periode_1.taxe}} </td>
   <td></td>
   <td> {{ts.tsf_periode_2.taxe}} </td>
   <td></td>
   <td> {{ts.tsf_periode_3.taxe}} </td>
   <td></td>
   <td> {{ts.tsf_periode_4.taxe}} </td>
   <td></td>
   <td> {{ts.production_tsf.calcule_production}} </td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanx for your answer, but it didn't work with me :'(

Comment: I have Django 2.2.15 and it's working fine. Could you tell the error if there any while using the syntax shared in the answer.